# Unresolved inclusion of Qt in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, qt, indexer

Eclipse fails to locate Qt includes. Likewise, it fails to provide auto-complete functionality for Qt classes.

I did Project -> Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> Add to the include directories of Qt in `/usr/include/qt4/`. This caused Eclipse to recognize certain certain classes such as `QString`; however, there is no auto-complete.

I have scoured the web to no avail. How do I make Eclipse index Qt into my project?

Edit: 12/20/12

I have solved my own problem. It appears order of the includes matter. I put

```
'usr/include/qt4'
'usr/include/qt4/Qt'
'usr/include/qt4/QtCore'
'usr/include/qt4/QtGui'
```

into `Project Properties -> C++ General -> Paths & Symbols`. I rebuilt and the auto-complete worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add several include directories, those listed by e.g. the command

```
 pkg-config --cflags QtGui QtXml QtSvg QtDBus
```

(and others Qt packages).

Comment: I have done just that, but auto-complete still does not work for Qt.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem - that's the index does not look for files without extension that's the case of qt headers.

Comment: i have filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=567594 for this issue